# RestKit sometimes give me "The operation couldn’t be completed"

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, restkit

Iam using RestKit to get objects from a PHP webservice 
my code is

```
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"1", @"user_id",nil];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/myURL" stringByAppendingQueryParameters:params]delegate:self];
```

but when I use it for the first time it gives me only 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain error 4.)" without any other errors, and when refreshing the page it load objects correctly
I have searched well and can't find such a problem

Anyone can help ?